How does reading 名乗り really work?
I know the reading 名乗り is an exclusive reading for proper nouns, the question is: Is there a way to create or decide on a new 名乗り reading? Would it be possible for a name to have a "double meaning" or more using the 名乗り reading? For example: Could 友 {しん} which would come from "真" mean "true friend" at the same time? And with a combination of kanjis there could be multiple meanings? The reason for this question is that I have a lot of fun playing with kanji and I always try to make them as deep as possible. But is it possible? (I know if I used that kind of name I should add furigana).

At least, as for 'Could 友{しん} which would come from "真" mean "true friend" at the same time? ', the answer is no.

しん is an on'yomo of another kanji. It doesn't work that way.

Ya, as @aguijonazo mentions, nanori readings generally cannot come from on'yomi, and must usually be based on kun'yomi. Note too that the readings, while kun'yomi based, often have nothing directly to do with the kanji used for the spelling.  See, for instance, the wide variety of spellings for the name Megumi, here at ENAMDICT. This approach of basically independent reading + spelling is similar to jukujikun.

Are you conflating 名乗り and キラキラネーム?

Just regarding the question in title, this Wikipedia article says:

人名訓（じんめいくん）は、日本人の人名に用いられる漢字のうち、人名用に宛てられた常用漢字や人名用漢字の特殊な訓読を指す。名乗り訓（なのりくん）ともいう1。多くの漢字辞典では音読、訓読とは別で読みを記載している場合があり、また人名専用の漢字辞典も存在するが、読みに際して厳密な法規制はないため（あまりにも本来の意味から逸れたり、甚だしく人名に適さなかったりすると、役所職員らの判断で許可を出さないことがある）、その多くは字意を反映したものとなっているものの、半ば慣習的な宛字となっている。

I bolded what is relevant. The gist is,

名乗り訓 is a special reading (different from usual on- or kun-reading) for names.
There is no legal restriction on reading of character
But the reading is expected to be reasonable as per the meaning of the character or as a human name
名乗り訓 is mostly conventional.

There's a list of reading in the linked page and as the last point says, 名乗り訓 is mostly a fixed set of irregular reading that is accepted for human names only. So if you create a reading of a character, it is not considered as one.
At the same time, there's no strict restriction. This means, if you are trying to use 友{しん} for your child (which I don't think is the case), you can go ahead, but it can be refused by the local officer, as mentioned above.

If you want to have fun with names, you can look up キラキラネーム, which takes lots of liberty on reading.
Taken from here

光宙 is read ぴかちゅう, the poke-mon. ぴか comes from onomatopoeia meaning light/flash, ちゅう is the normal reading for 宙.
今鹿 is read なうしか. なう comes from the English now meaning 今 and しか is the normal reading for 鹿.
美気意 is read みっきー. Here the reading is totally phonetic: み for 美, き for 気, い for 意.

Note that generally these names are considered ridiculous.
Also, even by the standard of キラキラネーム, reading a character 友 by a reading of a different character is not likely.

sorry again for the same question, so from what I (think) I understand these readings are only for names that already exist?  so the case is that 友 should be read as "めぐみ"?  Of course, I'm not considering options for joining kanji.

@TokamiChelsea It is rather that there is a list of conventionally accepted (reading, kanji) pairs. 友 is read とも or ゆう. Other readings are just outside convention (in naming context or not).

One thing you may be missing is, when native speakers think of a name, the first thing that they decide is either 1. names (pronunciation) itself or 2. a sequence of kanji that looks like a name. People usually do not think about meaning first (even if they do, ultimately they turn to a list of possible names, 'possible' meaning 'reasonable by the native speaker's instinct').

Basically, reading 友 as しん is as unlikely as pronouncing friend as true. 名乗り訓 is mostly based on the character itself, not a way to put double meaning on the character.
